# Unexpected error when deserializing unknown types with Json.Net

Tags: json.net

In the following code, I serialize an object using Json.Net. This Json has type names embedded. I then change one of the type names to induce an error (this is a test, I am dealing with a real issue in an existing project). When I deserialize the Json, I expect to get an object back that has a null value for the property with the fiddled type name. Instead the serializer craps out and returns null. Are my expectations correct? Can I change the settings somehow so that I will get a non-null object for my root object? Note that the second error that I get suggests that there is a bug in the serializer.

```
static public class JsonTest
{
    static public void Test()
    {
        // Create test object
        A a = new A
        {
            MyTest = new MyTest(),
        };

        // Serialize it. 
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        });

        // Fiddle class name to induce error
        json = json.Replace("+MyTest", "+MyTest2"); 

        // Before: {"MyTest":{"$type":"<Namespace>.JsonTest+MyTest, <Assembly>"}}
        // After: {"MyTest":{"$type":"<Namespace>.JsonTest+MyTest2, <Assembly>"}}

        // Deserialize
        A a2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            Error = (object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) =>
            {
                e.ErrorContext.Handled = true; // Should have only one error: the unrecognized Type
            }
        });

        // A second error occurs: Error = {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object....
        // a2 is null
    }

    public class A
    {
        public ITest MyTest { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITest { }
    public class MyTest : ITest { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1266) has been fixed in Json.NET [10.0.2](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.2) in [this submission](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/f88ae288bc00836760ee8dfab526e4b944a191bb).

**Original Answer**

This looks to be a bug in Json.NET.  If I set [`JsonSerializerSettings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_MetadataPropertyHandling.htm) then the problem goes away:

```
// Deserialize
A a2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead,
    Error = (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorContext.Path);
        e.ErrorContext.Handled = true; // Should have only one error: the unrecognized Type
    }
});

Debug.Assert(a2 != null); // No assert.
```

However, it should not be necessary to turn on this setting, which enables reading metadata properties including `"$type"` located anywhere in a JSON object, rather than just as the first property.  Most likely it coincidentally fixes the bug since it requires pre-loading the entire JSON object before beginning deserialization.

You could [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) if you want.

Debugging a bit, the problem seems to be that, because the inner `MyTest` object cannot be constructed, the exception is caught and handled by [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L2317) while populating the outer object `A`.  Because of this, the `JsonReader` does not get advanced past the inner, nested object, leaving the reader and serializer in an inconsistent state.  This accounts for the second exception and the eventual `Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object. Path ''` exception.

Comment: I reported this as an [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1266#event-1025062578), and it has been fixed.